# Text to Columns default [Excel]

Tags: microsoft-excel

Is it possible to change the Text to Columns defaults in Excel 2013?

The goal is to change it so that it *always* picks delimited and, by
default, has semicolumn be a "selected" delimiter.

[image]

Comment: Don't you want to change it every time you will use it? After the first time you use it, every time you Convert Text to Columns, the options you first choose will be selected. So you can click on Finish instead of Next and it will do the job for you.

Comment: Create a macro to do it.

Answer (score 0):

```
 Range(activecell).Select
    Selection.TextToColumns Destination:=Range(activecell), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
        TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=False, _
        Semicolon:=True, Comma:=False, Space:=False, Other:=False, FieldInfo _
        :=Array(Array(1, 1), Array(2, 1), Array(3, 1), Array(4, 1), Array(5, 1), Array(6, 1), _
        Array(7, 1), Array(8, 1), Array(9, 1), Array(10, 1), Array(11, 1), Array(12, 1), Array(13, 1 _
        ), Array(14, 1), Array(15, 1), Array(16, 1), Array(17, 1), Array(18, 1), Array(19, 1)), _
        TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
```

Then use the macro instead of the default "Text to Column"